# Using Same Value from Select Statement in an Insert Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, insert

I have an insert command with values are calculated based on currency value on another table. Sql code is something like

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6)
VALUES
(
value1 * (SELECT currency FROM currency_table WHERE date=date1),
value2 * (SELECT currency FROM currency_table WHERE date=date1),
value3 * (SELECT currency FROM currency_table WHERE date=date1),
value4 * (SELECT currency FROM currency_table WHERE date=date2),
value5 * (SELECT currency FROM currency_table WHERE date=date2),
value6 * (SELECT currency FROM currency_table WHERE date=date2),
)

UPDATE table1 
SET column1 = value7 * (SELECT currency FROM currency_table WHERE date=date1),
column2 = value8 * (SELECT currency FROM currency_table WHERE date=date1),
column3 = value9 * (SELECT currency FROM currency_table WHERE date=date1),
column4 = value10 * (SELECT currency FROM currency_table WHERE date=date2),
column5 = value11 * (SELECT currency FROM currency_table WHERE date=date2),
column6 = value12 * (SELECT currency FROM currency_table WHERE date=date2)
WHERE column7 = value13
```

So i get currency values 3 times. Consider this is an example becaue my actual query has this with 10 calls.

How can i change this query to get Currency value not 3 times but only 1 time.

Consider currency_table has only 1 row.

Forgot to mention this query is for sql server 2008

Comment: Do you need to do it in a single INSERT statement?

Comment: yes i need a single insert and update statement

Comment: @elevres Your Question seems to be very confusing for me. Once u calculated the values for **`column1,column2,column3`** (In ***Insert*** statement), then why do you want to update it once again ?

Comment: Probably these are not the same values.

Comment: yes they are not the same values, these queries and values are sample and insert and update scenarios are just example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert is ok with what Guneli has provided. 
Syntactically, the query is incorrect.
Use

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6)
SELECT value1*currency1, value2*currency1, value3*currency1,
       value4*currency2, value5*currency2, value6*currency2
FROM (select (select currency from currency_table where date = @date1) currency1,
(select currency from currency_table where date = @date2) currency2) A;
```

For update, you can use the following command.

```
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.column1 = value1 * c.currency1,
t1.column2 = value2 * c.currency1,
t1.column3 = value3 * c.currency1,
t1.Column4 = value4 * c.currency2,
t1.column5 = value5 * c.currency2,
t1.column6 = value6 * c.currency2
from table1 t1, 
(select (select currency from currency_table where date = @date1) currency1, 
   (select currency from currency_table where date = @date2) currency2) C
WHERE t1.column4 = value4
```

It will make a cross join with currency_table, and assuming currency_table is having single row, it will update correctly.

Comment: thank you very much ,but now i need further information , thats why i updated thw sql. Could you please look at it again ?

Comment: is it fixed date1, and date2 or it is also dynamic. Also these date1 and date2 are variables? or column from currency_table? It seems that you need to have a view, with two currency columns, and then you can do directly insert/update using that view.

Comment: they are just values and fixed.

Comment: these worked perfect. Thank you soo much. It really helped me a lot. Thank you very much. Thanks for the other guys responded too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1,column2,column3)
VALUES
SELECT value1*currency, value2*currency, value3*currency
FROM currency_table;
```

Comment: thank you, i guess this is what i need for my question. But i need further information, thats why i updated the sql in my question.

I need currency values based on date so when i need two currency value from two different dates, how can i write this in one single INSERT statement. I updated the sql above. Thanks for your answers because i'm newbie about SQL.

Comment: Wasn't it "UPDATE" rather than "INSERT" that was asked of?

Comment: It is both UPDATE and INSERT are asked for.

Comment: This method will not work for an UPDATE as MS SQL does not support  row-value constructors.

Answer (score 0):

What about a join? I am not sure on the condition as you select currency without any where clause.

```
UPDATE table1 t1 INNER JOIN currency_table c ON [condition??]
SET t1.column1 = value1 * c.currency,
t1.column2 = value2 * c.currency,
t1.column3 = value3 * c.currency,
WHERE t1.column4 = value4
```

Comment: Well even if there is only one row in the currency table i still would access it by its ID - just hoping that there will never be multiple results for "Select currency from currency_table" is not a good practice.